# Image url adding some of the pagespeed codes

Tags: image

I have  not loaded for any scripts but automatically added the pagespeed in image url adding some of the webp image  format. so how to rectify the error and images are not show.

xxx.com/pub/media/logo/stores/1/101x43xsarikart.png.pagespeed.ic.xwaQijPBK8.webp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using google speed module
https://youtu.be/6uCAdQSHhmA?t=1886

If you don't want that feature, turn it off.

Comment: How to check the  pagespeed extension in which file using magento 2 source code.kindly mentioned because,all files are searched,but not implemented.then how to i find  the data-pagespeed-no-defer script

Comment: You can check this link: https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-mod

Answer (score 0):

After debugging possibly everything I could, reading almost all posts concerning this issue and trying maybe all possible solutions to this issue, I added the following code in .htaccess file so that I disable mod_pagespeed apache module and everything worked again like a charm!

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps you.